# JQuery ajax post variable name id_ not allowed?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass with ajax post a variabile with name id_cat but with no success.

```
    var catid_1 = $("select#catid_1 option:selected").prop("value");

    $.post(urlpage,
    {
        id_cat: catid_1
    },      
    function(data){
        $("#res").html(data);
    });
```

I've tried with

```
"id_cat": catid_1
```

or

```
'id_cat': catid_1
```

but with no success. Only permit this

```
idcat: catid
```

unfortunately my variable should have the name id_cat, how could I solve this problem? thanks

EDIT

If I use idcat: catid_1 in my urlpage (var_dump($_POST) I get this

```
'idcat' => string '8' (length=1)
```

if I use id_cat: catid_1 I get nothing

Comment: What does "with no success" mean? Does it throw an error? If so, what's the error? If you're tempted to reply with "It's not working" or "Nothing happens" you need to take another look.

Comment: Not return $_POST['id_cat']

Comment: @Paolo Rossi: Could you try this one - 
    $.post(urlpage, { id_cat: catid_1 }, function (data) { $("#res").html(data); });

Comment: @Ishan Jain I edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.ajax` as in it you can use all ajax properties.

Below is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:urlpage,
    type: "POST"
    data:{ id_cat: catid_1},      
    success: function(data){
        $("#res").html(data);
        },
    error: function() {
        alert("error occured");
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's literally identical to the code they've posted, since `$.post()` calls `$.ajax()` internally. All you've added is the `error` handler, which doesn't answer the question.

Comment: OP is using post which not handles error handling, so $.ajax should be used for all ajax options

Comment: I've an error in SyntaxError: missing } after property list (data:{ id_cat: catid_1})

Comment: Put comma after post I forgot it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
             url: urlpage,
            contentType: "application/json", 
            dataType: "html",
            data: "{id_cat:'" + catid_1 + "'}",

            success: function (data) {
                 $("#res").html(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
         alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

This is the right way to pass the data in $.ajax. Also remember that the variable name must be "id_cat" in your webmethod.